# PowerApps Filter a Sharepoint list Gallery by a selected item from a related Sharepoint list Gallery

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have two Sharepoint lists, one called Vendors/Process, the other called Notes.

Vendors/Process is simply one column with a the name of a Vendor, or the name of a Process we follow, such as Springer Publishing, or IP Addresses.

Notes are records with multiple columns, such as Title, Vendor/Process, Status, Notes, etc.

The Vendor/Process column is related to Records. I can select multiple values in the Vendor column in Records. For example, I can select both Springer Publishing, and IP Addresses.

I have my PowerApp set up so I can click on a Vendor/Process title in Gallery1, and Gallery2 will being back all Notes that have been tagged with that Vendor/Process.

For example, if I create a Note and name it Springer IP addresses, I will tag it with both Springer Publishing, and IP Addresses, and this record should show up whether I click Springer Publishing, or IP Address.

I'm running into a delegation warning. I thought by Filtering Gallery2 by Gallery1 selected item, that this would take care of the delegation warning, but it has not. If I click a Vendor/Process, Notes will only show up if they are one of the first 2000 records.

Here is my function for Gallery1:

`SortByColumns(Search('Vendor/Process', TextInput2.Text, "Title"), "Title", Ascending)`

Function for Gallery2:

`Filter('Notes',Gallery4.Selected.Title in 'Vendor/Process'.Value)`

I will admit, I am new to PowerApps and I do not have a technical background.